# JS code in multi-condition and multi-increment is not working, I wondering what's wrong with it

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop

I tried to output the total and even number for x and y as below, but not working. I checked on the firebug to find the error and it said "Error: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable" 
Hope you understand what is asking. Thanks in advance.

```
var total = even = 0;
for (var x = 1, y = 1; x <= 10; x++, y++) {
  if ((y % 2) == 0) {
    even += y;
  }
  total += x;
}

document.write("Total : " + total + " even : " + even);
```

Comment: "Not working" is not a useful description of a problem. Please edit your question to describe in as much detail as possible what your code is supposed to do and what problem you're having.

Comment: Your code is fine.

Comment: This code works fine with output as Total : 55 even : 30. Check your complete code, problem may be at some other place